# Show clear button in readonly input box on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<input id="my-input" type="search" />
```

shows a 'x' to clear the input on mousehover.

This behaviour is lost when I do

```
<input id="my-input" type="search" readonly="readonly">
```

I've had to make my Datepicker input box readonly:

```
$("#my-input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).attr('readonly', 'true');
```

How can I retain the previous behaviour for this readonly input box?

Comment: Basically you can't. It's "readonly". The whole point of readonly is that the user is not allowed to change the value of the input. Why do you need a user to be able to "clear" an input that is readonly? OR Why is your input readonly if you want the user to be able to interact with it's value?

Comment: It’s readonly so that no invalid date can be entered. It’s still handy to be able to clear whatever date user selected in a single click.

Comment: So you'll have to make your own "clear" button. It's the only way. The browser displays the "x" for you to clear the input but it's not going to display that interactive "x" because you told it not to. You told it that the input was non-interactive by setting it to "readonly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="my-input" type="search" />
```

with

```
$("#my-input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

seems to achieve what I'm after.